# Elasticsearch get task ID from index name in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am performing a query + reindex on the fly in Java 8 using Elasticsearch 6.2, on AWS. I am also interfacing the ES cluster through a Jest client, again, with the Java APIs provided by the client's library. I return back the results of the query to the user and use those results to start a reindex operation in the background for later use. The reindex operation can be semi-long running and take more than just a few or several seconds. I obviously know what my new index name is, but working in a stateless application on a server, I cannot save the task ID returned from the reindex API to query later, I need to look it up by other means. Doing a little research, I came across this API call in Kibana:

```
GET /_tasks?actions=*reindex
```

which will return all tasks that are currently reindexing, or an empty list. From there, I can get the parent task ID and query it for status. This may be a problem as I might have more than one reindex operation happening on the ES cluster at once.

Is there a more intelligent or straight-forward approach to my problem?